# Get any usb disk info with Adobe AIR

Tags: actionscript-3, air, adobe, usb, disk

I've been struggeling with that for a few days so I come and post here.

I have an air application running from an USB drive.
I simply want to be able to detect if the files have been moved on a new USB disk.

Is there any way to get any information on the disk like :

- any hardware info (ID, brand, Serial, ...) from the USB disk the file are on ?
- the usb disk size (not spaceAvailable as it's likely to change)
- anything else that would not be copied from one disk to the other ?

The only thing I have acces is the name of the disk but two disks can easily have the same name.

I tried as well to use the "downloaded from Internet" Flag but it does'nt seem to be working.

Thank you so much if you can help me.

MrKalten

Comment: I doubt you can get any of this info from AS3, but presumably you can use a Native Extension to get the info you want.

Comment: I haven't ever seen something like this and in reading on http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/StorageVolume.html I don't see anything like what you're looking for next step if nothing in fact exists I think is to look into native extensions.  Ah see pixel elephant beat me to it.

Answer (score 3):

Post Adobe AIR 2.0, they have introduced a new apis to handle StorageVolumes
You can get the reference and example here.
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/reference/html/flash/filesystem/StorageVolumeInfo.html

Use this method to get all the storage volumes connected external/internal.

```
import flash.filesystem.StorageVolume;
import flash.filesystem.StorageVolumeInfo;

var volumes = StorageVolumeInfo.storageVolumeInfo.getStorageVolumes(); 
for (var i = 0; i < volumes.length; i++) 
{ 
    var volume:StorageVolume = volumes[i];
    trace ("Name ::" + volume.name);
    trace ("Path ::" + volume.rootDirectory.nativePath); 
    trace ("isRemovable ::" + volume.isRemovable);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be another way to expose that information to AIR: http://www.mikechambers.com/blog/2008/01/17/commandproxy-net-air-integration-proof-of-concept/